# Pros and cons of a PhD in material science for someone passionate about research

Tags: phd, research-process, industry, engineering

I am a material science Masters graduate i have a double bachelor degree and double Masters degree (From 3 countries) now i am working at a reputable automotive company. However, My passion is in research, I tried many times to get a PhD with no luck (in Germany and parts in europe). until i gave up and started working in the industry.

My questions are: **If i want to work in research (and not necessary continue in the academic track). Does it make sense to still try and get a PhD?**

**If i want to go back to industry again, Will my PhD title affect my chances to go back in the industry and will i have to stick to academic career?**

**Would it be just easier to get a job at a research company/facility and just work there without a PhD degree?**

I keep hearing mixed opinions about all the questions i asked. I would really love to hear feedback particularly from with a background in material science

Comment: "in research (and not necessary continue in the academic track)". In academic track there are two options a) Being a professor c) Being a researcher e.g., in publicly funded research institutes. Obtaining either type of positions is hard. The third option (outside academia) is working as a researcher in industry. Getting a researcher position in industry is also very hard. Summary: Getting a research position is hard by definition, Also, since you were not enrolled in a PhD program, how do you know that you will enjoy research?

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate because I think the main thrust of your question is answered by the linked question.  Your question has a lot of parts, though, so if you want more information on a specific part, I suggest either refining your question or starting a new one focused on the specific element.  In general, though, speaking as a researcher in industry, I have to disagree with @Alexandros: there's a *lot* of good PhD-level industrial jobs out there, if you don't mind your research being applications-focused.

Comment: @Alexandros, I have enjoyed working on several projects through out my bachelor and masters (either thesis or project work) and i know that it working on research gives me joy, as i want to implement new ideas and discover new characteristics.